# how to send a json object as a parameter to a native query calling a procedure?

Tags: java, json, oracle, procedure, nativequery

hi guys my dout is i got a jsonobject and im sending this object as a parameter to a nativeQuery:

```
Query query = entityManager
            .createNativeQuery("{call myprocedure(?)} ");
    query.setParameter(1, myjson);
```

i got the error bellow:

```
10:54:06,362 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 907, SQLState: 42000
10:54:06,362 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis
```

my json object:

```
{"phone":4834378165,"observation":"","colaborator_open":"S","reason":"asdf","location_description":"","residence_number":"","colaborator_registration":901546,"amount":0,"street_id":"0","colaborator_type":"T","name":"client","solicitation_type":"I","is_printed":"N","subsidiary_type":5,"service_code":5930,"amount_informed":0,"staff_visit":"N"}
```

Comment: solve by change the procedure by a fuction and invoque with:

Answer (score 0):

Solved  changing the procedure for a function and invoking like this:

```
 select  myFunction(?) from dual
```